# How do I exit coasting when a key is pressed?

Tags: touchpad, synaptic

I have enabled coasting on my touchpad:

```
$ synclient -l | grep -i coast
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
```

It works fine. However, if I start coasting, take my hand off the touchpad and press another key, it acts like a combo of that key and scroll. For example, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> after I start coasting will result in this page being zoomed in (or out). Can I trigger an immediate exit from coasting when a key is pressed?

I use:

- Arch Linux, GNOME Shell  3.16.2
- Ubuntu 14.04, GNOME Shell 3.10.4